# Integrate twitter digits with a cordova/phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

Digit released its Web SDK not too long ago, however I'm having some issues integrating it with my phonegap/cordova app.

I have tried using the inappbrowser plugin but since digits uses the postMessage api to transfer data between windows and it seems like apache will never support this with cordova/phonegap (or at least they are taking forever - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4897) this doesnt seem to work so well.

I know the digits team is probably working on solution to integrate with a phonegap/cordova app but currently there are none and theres no indication when one will come out.

Is there a solution out there to integrate phonegap/cordova with twitter digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have worked hard and researched many different things, most of which have lead me to a deadend.

TJ VanToll has posted a great [work around](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser) to the postMessage API with the inappbrowser plugin, however this doesnt seem to work so well with my android (I haven't tried iphone). TJ's solution has inspired my solution to oAuth with digits-cordova.

You can find my solution at https://github.com/yangli1990/digits-cordova.git

Or simply use bower to install it

keep in mind this solution will be obsolete if the fabrics team come up with a more native way to integrate digits with cordova/phonegap apps.

```
bower install digits-cordova
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

/* Optional cordova plugins */
cordova plugin add com.simonmacdonald.telephonenumber
cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.sms
```

this library works well because you can also optionally allow your app to autofill phone number and location and also intercept SMS to auto proceed.

In your html make sure you have the appropriate javascript links

```
<!-- optional -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/telephonenumber.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/SMS.js"></script>

<!-- required -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/inappbrowser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/digitsCordova.js"></script>
```

In your app.js

```
function openDigits(){
  var digits = new DigitsCordova('gmoaaZhEG88hMQUdpWHnF1IAz'); //Replace with your own consumerKey
    digits.open()
        .successCallback(function(loginResponse){
            var oAuthHeaders = loginResponse.oauth_echo_headers;
            var verifyData = {
                authHeader: oAuthHeaders['X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization'],
                apiUrl: oAuthHeaders['X-Auth-Service-Provider']
            };

            $.post('/verify', verifyData)
                .done(function(){ window.reload(); });
        }).failCallback(function(error){
            //error
        }).errorCallback(function(error){
            //error
        })
}

openDigits();
```

You can read about the api at the github page, there are some options you can choose to either turn on or off autofill and smsIntercept.

Comment: After Login in twitter using DIgits, Can I post tweets to my account using auth_token?? If yes how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure about this one, I don't think your phone number is connected to your twitter account - at least it's not compulsory for digits to work. AFAIK digits main functionality works as a mobile number authentication, not sure if it works alongside with twitter.

Comment: I have got the response after the phone number verification. It contains `X-Auth-Service-Provider` and `X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization`. How do I use these to verify the user?

Answer (score -1):

your work great. because it's very difficult to implement. I try you API but it's not work perfect. i.e. some work but some not. like not open keypad when i focus on text box and not open popup menu of countries.... if you get me some advice so your welcome...

Comment: It seems to work fine for me, I'm not sure why your one is behaving like this.